# Do Page Faults automatically invoke the Operating System?

Tags: linux, exception, operating-system, page-fault

When a user-space application incurs a page fault, is the Operating System (OS) automatically invoked upon detection of the fault or must the OS be invoked manually?

For Linux and x86, I understand there are checks for privilege level of process invoking the interrupt/exception handler, but am confused as to whether failing these checks automatically invoke the OS to handle the page fault or not.

Comment: Page faults are handled entirely in the hardware and OS, user-mode code never detects them.

Comment: So upon a page fault being incurred, is the fault handler automatically invoked? Is this implemented in hardware or software (or a combination)? Does the privilege switch (from ring 3 to 0) also occur simultaneously? Thank you.

Comment: [Page Fault Exception Handler](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/understanding-the-linux/0596005652/ch09s04.html)

Comment: Thank you for the link. From that, what confuses me is how the do_page_fault() function even gets invoked (for example, is it hardwired to occur upon a page fault)?

Comment: It's from the operating system's interrupt handler.

Comment: All hardware interrupts are handled by the OS.

Comment: So the interrupt signal that is generated by hardware causes a privilege switch from user-space to kernel-space (if necessary), then begins execution of the respective interrupt/exception handler?

Comment: Yes, that's not specific to page faults, all interrupts work like that. There must be an earlier chapter in that book that explains this.